# Koin inject viewmodel into Composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, koin

I am trying to use Koin to inject my viewModel (which has some dependencies as well) like this:

[image: Unresolved Reference]

I don't understand why it cannot find getViewModel when I have the following import:

[image: Koin import]

I am using this Koin version: implementation **"io.insert-koin:koin-android:$koin_version"**

where $koin_version = '3.2.0-beta-1'

Any thoughts why my import is ignored here?

Comment: Check out [Why should I not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3585796) and replace images with [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) code

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're using a wrong import, you should use:

```
import org.koin.androidx.compose.getViewModel
```

To use it you need the following dependency:

```
implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-compose:$koinVersion")
```

Comment: not working on Koin '3.2.1' and Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1

Comment: Same for me in a Compose multiplatform project. The import does not work. Is that an Android only extension?

Comment: @mipa I guess so, as it requires `ViewModel` subclass which is android only

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I did it in koin 3.3.2

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(viewModel: PokemonViewModel = koinViewModel()) {
}
```

I also added `koin-core` to `build.gradle(:app)`

```
def koin_version = '3.3.2'
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-core:$koin_version"
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
implementation 'io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-compose:3.4.1'
```

[SOURCE](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/compose)